# Add input value to another value as a total sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a budget app where the user can put in a product and a price. I want it to display the total cost by adding each input value (HTML5 type=number) to the next number that is put in with the next added line.

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.food').click(function() {
    var $frm = $(this).parent();
    var toAdd = $frm.children(".productInput").val();
    var addPrice = $frm.children(".priceInput").val();
    var addAmount = $frm.children(".amountInput").val();


    var div = $("<div>");
    div.append("<p>" + addAmount + "</p>", "<p id='product'> " + toAdd + " </p>", "<p>" + addPrice + "</p>");

    $frm.parent().children(".messages").append(div);

    $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price" + addAmount * addPrice);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <h3>Shopping list</h3>
  <div class="line">
    <div>
      <input class='amountInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000' step='1'>
      <input class='productInput' type="text" name="message" value="">
      <input class='priceInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000000' step='0.01'>
      <button class="food">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="messages">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="totalPrice">
```

How can I do this? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a global variable outside your function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var totalPrice=0;

$('.food').click(function() {
..
```

do this while calculating total price

```
totalPrice = totalPrice + (addAmount * addPrice);
$(".totalPrice").text("Total Price" + totalPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `totalPrice` variable outside of your click function. Then add your `addAmount * addPrice` to the `totalPrice` every time you add a new item. Then display the `totalPrice` in your `.totalPrice` div instead of the `addAmount * addPrice` of the last added item.

You may also want to add a call to `.toFixed()` on your `totalPrice` when displaying it. Calling `totalPrice.toFixed(2)` will ensure that you display only two decimal places, so that it's a proper format for monetary values.

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var totalPrice = 0;

  $('.food').click(function() {
    var $frm = $(this).parent();
    var toAdd = $frm.children(".productInput").val();
    var addPrice = $frm.children(".priceInput").val();
    var addAmount = $frm.children(".amountInput").val();


    var div = $("<div>");
    div.append("<p>" + addAmount + "</p>", "<p id='product'> " + toAdd + " </p>", "<p>" + addPrice + "</p>");

    $frm.parent().children(".messages").append(div);
    
    totalPrice += addAmount * addPrice;

    $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice.toFixed(2));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <h3>Shopping list</h3>
  <div class="line">
    <div>
      <input class='amountInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000' step='1'>
      <input class='productInput' type="text" name="message" value="">
      <input class='priceInput' type='number' name='quantity' min='0' max='1000000' step='0.01'>
      <button class="food">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="messages">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="totalPrice"></div>
```